# Error in Sys.sleep(reset + 2) : invalid 'time' value

Tags: r, rtweet

I am currently trying to download data using the search_tweets command from the rtweet package. I have a list of over 400 requests that I want to loop it over. The code seems to run without problems, yet, after a while this happens:

> retry on rate limit...
> waiting about 16 minutes... #which it then counts down#
> Error in Sys.sleep(reset + 2) : invalid 'time' value

Searching for related questions, I only found this: https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues/277. There they say that in the latest rtweet version this issue has been solved. But I am using the latest R and rtweet versions.
Has someone experienced a similar issue? And how have you been able to solve it?

This is the code I am using. Please don't hesitate to tell me if it is a mistake in the code that causes the problem. I was wondering e.g. if it is possible to include a condition that only runs the next request as soon as the first request is fully downloaded?

```
for (x in 1:length(mdbs)) {
  mdbName = mdbs[x] 
  print(mdbName)
  myMDBSearch = paste0(mdbName,"lang:de -filter:retweets") 
  print(myMDBSearch)

  req <- search_tweets(
    q = myMDBSearch, 
    n = 100000,
    retryonratelimit = TRUE, 
    token = bearer_token(),
    parse=TRUE
    )
  
  data_total <- rbind(data_total,req) 
  
  print("sleeping 5 seconds")
  Sys.sleep(5)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: There is some rate limit on how many tweets you can download in a day. It seems you have exhausted the limit which is causing the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This astonishes me, as I have an acdemic twitter API and am using the v2 bearer_token as authentification. Here it only lists the following limitations: > 450 requests per 15 min with OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/migrate (as I only seek to run 405 requests, this limit should not apply).

Comment: Furthermore, with the download as far as it got rn, I only got a total of 50000 tweets for 10 requests. When I run a single request without n=limitation, it downloads the full more than 100.000 without any problems. Can you tell me where the tweet per day limit is written down?